# Social login in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

Right now, I'm trying to setup some social logins (facebook and twitter) in a website I'm currently developing.

But now, I'm stuck in some point. I'm just following HWIOAuthBundle's documentation:
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-configuring_the_security_layer.md
But I'm stuck at step 3-A.

I "can't" understand that point. I'm not experienced in creating services, nor using them... What does the first paraph mean?

So guys, do you know any step by step guide to achieve what I'm trying to do?

I will be around, refreshing this question, so I can answer any question you may ask to me asap.

Thank you.

P.S.: Sorry if I'm not clear at all, or if I didn't provide any necessary info. Im not so much experienced in Symfony, I just know the basics (routing, controllers, entities, repositories), so forgive me, please.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, if you want to use the HWIOAuthBundle, please, read [this article](http://www.diegocaprioli.com/adding-hwioauthbundle-to-your-symfony2-project/) about a personal experience installing this bundle.

I followed these instructions, step-by-step and it worked for me.

On the other hand, you can use the FOS' bundles proposed by Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider using [Friends of Symfony](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony) bundles.

For Facebook, [FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle).

For Twitter, consider [FOSTwitterBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSTwitterBundle).

This way you will have a much better life.

Comment: I will check it out when I get home. Is it easier to implement? Thank you for the tip. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Not that its easier, but that it works ;) . JK, its really easy!

Comment: FOSTwitter Bundle now provides the following message in Github: "UNMAINTAINED. Please use HWIOAuthBundle as a replacement for FOSTwitterBundle."