# Undefined method registerNamespaces() symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I'm following this FOSTwitterBundle documentation:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSTwitterBundle

I did it all step by step, but when I access my site, i get this error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::registerNamespaces() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\app\autoload.php on line 16
```

My autoload.php is like this:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
        // ...
        'FOS'    => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
        // ...
  ));

return $loader;
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 9):

for symfony 2.*
replace this

```
$loader->add('FOS' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles');
```

with

```
$loader->add('FOS', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles');
```

Answer (score 6):

The basic problem is that the installation directions are for Symfony 2.0.  You are using S2.1.  I have not poked around in the twitter bundle.  Hard to say if it will even run under 2.1.  Installing it via git submodule instead of using composer seems strange.

Try starting over and adding: "friendsofsymfony/twitter-bundle": "dev-master" to your composer.json and doing an install.  This should bring down the packages and take care of autoloading for you.

Otherwise, replace:

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array('FOS'    => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'));
with
$loader->add('FOS' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles');
```

S2.1 uses a different class loader than S2.0 with a different interface.  It will at least get you past the error message.

But again, try the composer route first and then maybe submit a patch to the project to update the readme file.

Comment: As another comment around says, the add is different in 2.x and should be $loader->add('FOS', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles');

Answer (score 0):

OAuth?
I used https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle no long time ago.
How to integrate with FOSUB: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/81

Comment: I tried this one, but got stuck, here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270150/social-login-in-symfony2 As you can see someone recommended that Bundle. Is this a loop? hah!

Comment: Funny))) I too long to understand, but understanding it after a careful reading of several attempts by manual of integration.

Comment: In integration issue described how to use google service, for twitter it will be the same